# Minimum Distance between two position vectors without Calculus

Tags: vectors

I have tried to make both p and q such that they are equal so the displacement between them is 0. Assuming the displacement is 0, I then tried to find the magnitude equating it to 0. I'm not able to understand how to solve this.

> Points $P$ and $Q$ have position vectors $p=i+j+3 k$ and $q=(2+t) {i}+(1-t) {j}+(1+t){k} .$ Find the value of $t$ for
> which the distance $P Q$ is the minimum possible and find this minimum distance.

This is the answer: $t= \frac13$ and distance is  $\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$

Comment: It depents a little bit on what you know. The equation for $q$ determines a line. And the shortest distance of a point is given by the point on the line s.t.  if you connect the point with your original point the resulting line and your original line form a right angle. Can you find it with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First determine an expression for the vector $\vec{PQ} $ by taking the difference between the given position vectors.

$\vec{PQ} = (1+t)\underline i + (-t)\underline j + (t-2) \underline k$

Now find an expression for the magnitude (length) of that vector in terms of $t$.

$|\vec{PQ}| = \sqrt{(1+t)^2 + t^2+ (t-2)^2} = \sqrt{3t^2-2t+5} = \sqrt{3(t-\frac 13)^2 + \frac{14}{3}}$

You want to mimimise that expression, and it's easier with completing the square as I did above. Note that the square part $(t - \frac 13)^2 \geq 0$ for real $t$, so the magnitude is minimised when the square part is zero, i.e. when $t =\frac 13$ and the minimal magnitude is $\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$